# $a^2+b^2+c^2=nd^2$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

This from the $2022$ Francophone Mathematics Olympiad:

> Find the smallest natural number $n$ such that the only solution to: $a^2+b^2+c^2=nd^2$
> $(a,b,c,d$ are intgers$)$ is $(0,0,0,0)$

Here is my solution:

> For $n≤6$, we can see that the condition is not satisfied. Let's show that $n=7$ is the desired one. Suppose not: if $d$ is odd then working mod $8$ shows that there are no solutions. If $d$ is even, then we let $(a_0,b_0,c_0,d_0)$ be the smallest solution in which one of $a_0,b_0,c_0$ is not zero. Then working mod $4$ tells us that $a_0,b_0,c_0$ must all be even. And we have a smaller solution $(a_0/2,b_0/2,c_0/2,d_0/2)$.

Are there any other approaches different than mine?

Comment: I assume you mean "natural number" not "integer" for $n$.  Aside from that detail, your argument looks solid.

Comment: @lulu Yes, thank you!

Comment: If you were writing this for an actual competition, I'd suggest writing out solutions for $n≤6$.  It's easy, but worth taking the time for.

Comment: Yes, I did write the solutions in the actual competition. But I guess most people here can easily find those solutions.

Comment: A little typo, it should be $d_0/2$ too.

Comment: @jjagmath Corrected!

Comment: @jjagmath Although it is not necessary for our argument, if we can get $a,b,c$ to be zero, then $d$ will necessarily be zero.

Comment: Yes, but if $(a_0, b_0, c_0,d_0)$ is a solution you want to find an smaller **solution**. $(a_0/2, b_0/2, c_0/2,d_0)$ won't be a solution.

Comment: @jjagmath Yes, you are right!

Comment: The usual statement is that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$   integrally represents all positive integers except $4^k (8n+7)$  where $k,n \geq 0$  Worth making a clean argument for $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \neq 4^k (8n+7).$  The other direction is due to Gauss, by which it follows that all numbers are the sum of three triangular numbers.  Once you have the $\neq$  part, then throw in the $7d^2 $

Comment: @WillJagy Can you provide a source talking about that?

Comment: I posted an excerpt from a book I like. See also http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/

Comment: The result Will Jagy refers to is [Legendre's three-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem). The Wikipedia article has some references. There are many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leonard E. Dickson
*Modern Elementary Theory of Numbers*
1939

from pages 11, 112, 113

[image]